# Retriving the value from textfields having same class in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Firstly I wanna check the given value in textfield is Number or not.

But I have number of textfields ,the number is depending upon dynamic value from php&yii like as follows

```
<?php foreach($model->getData() as $donation){  ?>
     Donation For <?php echo  $donation['DonationName'];?>
     <label><b>$</b> <input class="textfld3" style="width:75%" title="First Name" placeholder="Amount" type="text">
    </label>
<?php } ?>
```

so I wanna get the value of the textfield or textfields in js..

I had also used the jsfunction as

```
var texts= $(".textfld3").map(function() {
   return $(this).val();
}).get();
alert(texts);
```

but all the values are showing in alert box along with commas

how should i get the value of textfiled or textfields to check whether it is number or not in js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through all the textfield using `$(".textfld3").each(function() {` and find value of textfield one after another. If a textfield having a non numeric value then show alert message and will focus on that textfield.

```
$(".textfld3").each(function() {
   var currentVal = $(this).val();
   if(isNaN(currentVal)){
        alert("Please enter numeric value");
        $(this).focus();
        return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: this solution suits my problem ..thank you so much @Rahul Patel ,it is very helpfull and you saved my time....

Comment: You are welcome mate. Really happy that I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick view into your code, it looks to me, `texts` is an array, so you could run through this array

```
var texts= $(".textfld3").map(function() {
       return $(this).val();
    }).get();
for ( var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++ ) {
 alert(texts[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `key` and `value` parameter in map function so you can return value of all text fields by value, here `ele` variable is value which is reference one element of that class selector

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
var texts= $(".textfld3").map(function(key,ele) {
       return $(ele).val();
       //return ele.value
    }).get();
    console.log(texts);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><b>$</b> <input class="textfld3" style="width:75%" title="First Name" placeholder="Amount" type="text">
    </label>
<hr>
<label><b>$</b> <input class="textfld3" style="width:75%" title="First Name" placeholder="Amount" type="text">
    </label>
<hr>
<label><b>$</b> <input class="textfld3" style="width:75%" title="First Name" placeholder="Amount" type="text">
    </label>
<hr>
<label><b>$</b> <input class="textfld3" style="width:75%" title="First Name" placeholder="Amount" type="text">
    </label>
<hr>
<button id="btn"> Get Values</button>
```

Comment: Thank you @HareshVidja for reply but i had finished it ..I also tried above code as you said but i shows data seperating with commas...anyway thank you once again

Comment: in alert, if you pass array its shows comma separated, it not actually comma separated. I have updated with console.log(), if you like it mark as correct.. thanks anyways :)